# Why am I getting the error "Unknown data property" when the field exists?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to grab all of the fields of a node (which I am doing by using array_keys). At this point, I want to feed them all to `entity_metadata_wrapper()`, and grab their values.

I will then, if they are strings, print them to a PDF document using TCPDF's `Text()` function.

Everything looks like it will work correctly; however, certain fields give an error as such:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_grade. in
>   EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()

The field exists in my node, though.

```
'field_grade' => 
    array (size=13)
      'default_value' => null
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => 
        array (size=4)
```

This is the code I am using.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$trip_fields = field_info_instances('node', 'trip');
$trip_fieldskeys = array_keys($trip_fields);
$margintop = 0;

foreach($trip_fieldskeys as $item) {
  $value = $wrapper->$item->value();
  if (gettype($value) == "string") {
    $pdf->Text(0, $margintop, $value, false, false, true, 0, 0,
       '', false, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M', false);
    $margintop = $margintop + 25;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: This was a while ago, but I believe so. I'll look up what was done and reply back here in a bit.

Comment: Is it possible that there are some nodes that you are running through entity_metadata_wrapper() that are missing a value for field_grade? That happened to me recently.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a custom field that you have defined in your module (using `hook_field_info()`) then you need to add a `property_type` to your field info.  See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/property-info-for-fields for an example and https://www.drupal.org/node/905580 for a full list of possible types.

If your field is a complex (multiple value) data structure you may also additionally need to include `property_callbacks` as well.  See http://d7.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/describe-field-properties-make-custom-fields-work-entity-metadata-wrappers for a good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

PHP fatal errors when calling `$wrapper->field_foo->value()` on an empty $wrapper. You need check that node have this field before call `$wrapper->field_foo->value()`. That Exception handling, be careful with `EntityMetadataWrapper`. And you can try with:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);// you need sure with varibale $node
foreach ($wrapper->getPropertyInfo() as $key => $val) {
    $value = $wrapper->$key->value();
    if (gettype($value) == "string") {
   $pdf->Text(0, $margintop, $value, false, false, true, 0, 0,
       '', false, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M', false);
   $margintop = $margintop + 25;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used FPDI Library for PDF Creation for Particular Content Type Node

```
    /* PDf Creationg Start */
    $pdf=new PDF_HTML_Table();  
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetXY(10.0,5.0);
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth');
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(4.0);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Your Title',false);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $title_page = 'Dated : '.date('jS F Y');    
    $pdf->Text(10,28,$title_page);          
    $pdf->SetFontSize(7);
    $header=array('your_field_no1','your_field_no2','your_field_no_n..');
    $rows = array();    

  /* Get Node Content */
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'your_content_type_name')               
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1, '=')
  ->propertyOrderBy('created','DESC')
  ->fieldCondition('field_name', 'value', $_GET['mname'],'=');
  $results = $query->execute();     

    if (isset($results['node'])) {
      $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
       $counter = 0;          
      foreach($nodes as $row) {
          $data = array();  
        if(sizeof($row->your_field_no1) > 0)
            {
                $your_data_array[] = $row->your_field_no1['und'][0]['value'];
            }

       if(sizeof($row->your_field_no2) > 0)
            {
                $your_data_array[] = $row->your_field_no2['und'][0]['value'];
            }
         // and so on..
         $rows[] = $data;
      }

    }  
   $pdf->Ln(35);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
        $pdf->SetWidths(array(40,40,40,40,40,40,50));
        $pdf->SetAligns('C');           
        $pdf->FilterRow($data_header);
        $pdf->SetWidths(array(40,40,40,40,40,40,50)); 
        $pdf->FilterRow($data); 
   $filename = "your_desired_name_plus_".date('jS-F-Y-h-i-s').'.pdf';
   $pdf->Output($filename,"D");
```

and it's working on my site... hope this helps